# count number of items in a row in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

I have a list of students that shows whether they were present or absent from a particular class.

```
    CREATE TABLE classlist
        (`id` int, `studentid` int, `subjectid` int, `presentid` int)
    ;

    CREATE TABLE student
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(4))
    ;

    CREATE TABLE subject
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(4))
    ;

    CREATE TABLE classStatus
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(8))
    ;

    INSERT INTO classlist
        (`id`, `studentid`, `subjectid`, `presentid`)
    VALUES
        (1, 111, 1, 1),
        (2, 222, 3, 0),
        (3, 333, 2, 1),
        (4, 111, 4, 0),
        (5, 111, 1, 1),
        (6, 222, 3, 0),
        (7, 333, 2, 1),
        (8, 111, 4, 0),
        (9, 111, 4, 0),
        (10, 111, 4, 0),
        (11, 111, 1, 1),
        (12, 333, 3, 1),
        (13, 333, 2, 1),
        (14, 333, 3, 1)
    ;

    INSERT INTO student
        (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES
    (111, 'John'),
    (222, 'Kate'),
    (333, 'Matt')
    ;

    INSERT INTO subject
        (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES
    (1, 'MATH'),
    (2, 'ENG'),
    (3, 'SCI'),
    (4, 'GEO')
    ;

    INSERT INTO classStatus
        (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES
    (0, 'Absent'),
    (1, 'Present')
    ;
```

See Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2d93/5

I can count who is absent and present overall with something like the below.

```
    SELECT
       studentid,
       students.name AS NAME,
       SUM(presentid = 1) AS present,
       SUM(presentid = 0) AS absent

    FROM classlist
    INNER JOIN student as students ON classlist.studentid=students.id

     GROUP BY studentid, NAME
```

But I want to know how many classes in a row a student has attended/missed, so that the teachers can easily see if someone has missed a lot of time or someone is rewarded for good attendance etc. I have seen some posts which talk about streaks but none of them seem to match the way the data has been presented to me so I am not sure how to acheive this?

Just to be clear based on my sample data below the out put for the streaks should be.

```
        (1, 111, 1, 1), /* John Present 1 times in a row */
        (2, 222, 3, 0), /* Kate Absent 1 times in a row */
        (3, 333, 2, 1), /* Matt Present 1 times in a row */
        (4, 111, 4, 0), /* John Absent 1 times in a row */
        (5, 111, 1, 1), /* John Present 1 times in a row */
        (6, 222, 3, 0), /* Kate Absent 2 times in a row */
        (7, 333, 2, 1), /* Matt Present 2 times in a row */
        (8, 111, 4, 0), /* John Absent 1 times in a row */
        (9, 111, 4, 0), /* John Absent 2 times in a row */
        (10, 111, 4, 0), /* John Absent 2 times in a row */
        (11, 111, 1, 1), /* John Present 1 times in a row */
        (12, 333, 3, 1), /* Matt Present 3 times in a row */
        (13, 333, 2, 1), /* Matt Present 4 times in a row */
        (14, 333, 3, 1) /* Matt Present 5 times in a row */
        /*Showing the latest status for each user*/
        /* John Present 1 times in a row */
        /* Kate Absent 2 times in a row */
        /* Matt Present 5 times in a row */
```

John present 1.

Kate absent 2.

Matt Present 5.

Comment: can you display the output?

Comment: Please read about database normalisation.

Comment: @Hammerite thanks for the feedback, I have edited the question to more closely reflect what I am working with (obviousally less data in this question but structure is the same). I am now at the same point as I was in the inital question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give the count of the consecutive rows with the same value as the last row:

```
select
  classlist.studentid,
  student.name,
  classStatus.name status,
  count(*) presentcnt
from
  classlist inner join student
  on classlist.studentid=student.id
  inner join classstatus
  on classlist.presentid=classstatus.id
  inner join (
    select
      studentid,
      max(case when presentid=0 then id end)  max_0,
      max(case when presentid=1 then id end)  max_1
    from classlist
    group by studentid
  ) s
  on coalesce(classlist.id>least(max_0,max_1) and
       classlist.id<=greatest(max_0,max_1),1)
  and s.studentid=classlist.studentid
group by classlist.studentid
```

On the subquery I'm extracting the max id where presentid = 0 and the max id where presentid = 1.

On the outer query I'm extracting and counting all rows where id is > than the least of max_0 and max_1, and <= than the greatest of those two. No matter what the last value is, these are all the rows with the same value as the last one.

If either `max_0` or `max_1` is null, it means that all rows have just one value, 1 or 0, and we have to get all of them. If one of max_0 or max_1 is null, the whole conditions will be null as well. Using `Coalesce( condition, 1`) I'm returning all rows in that case.

Notice that I am grouping by `classlist.studentid` and showing some nonaggregated columns, but this is a situation in which it is allowed since all nonaggregated columns have the same value.

Comment: @SirRufo this does look good, the only thing that is a concern is that you can't really tell if the count is present or absent which you can in yours?

Comment: @ak85 you should check this again ... i just edited this answer ;o) the state is there but was not shown by SQLFiddle ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo thanks for the upvote, and for the edit :) without an alias, SQLFiddle only shows the first column if they have the same name :)

Comment: @fthiella `+1` for hunting the bounty ;) Fast performance and `ANSI`!

Comment: @bonCodigo thanks :) I'm not sure if least and greatest are ANSI, and also the use of COALESCE(..., 1) with booleans... but it's just "plain" SQL and can be made ansi if needed :) I can write the query this way because there are just two values, present and absent, otherwise it would be more complicated :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?:

```
SELECT
   studentid,
   name,
   SUM(present = 1) AS present,
   SUM(present = 0) AS absent,
   count(subject) as classTimes,
   subject
   FROM your_table GROUP BY studentid, name,subject
```

Comment: Thanks, I am more after how many classes in a row they have attended/missed. I am not quite sure that this does this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.studentid, s.name, IF(presentid = 1,  'present', 'absent') STATUS, 
       ABS(SUM(IF(presentid = 1, 1, -1))) AS presentcnt
FROM classlist A 
INNER JOIN student s ON A.studentid = s.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id, studentid 
           FROM classlist GROUP BY studentid
          ) B ON A.studentid = B.studentid AND A.id = B.id 
GROUP BY A.studentid
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5445/5)

**OUTPUT**

```
| STUDENTID | NAME |  STATUS | PRESENTCNT |
-------------------------------------------
|       111 | John | present |          1 |
|       222 | Kate |  absent |          2 |
|       333 | Matt | present |          5 |
```

Comment: This nearly seems to work except if I run your query on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45ed3/1 it has John as absent 1 class when his last class was present(=1)?

Comment: Do you want present, absent status on last row of each student?

Comment: Yes but counting how many times in a row that status exists? If that makes sense?

Comment: This looks great for the current data set thanks however if I change for example (10, 111, 'John', 4, 0) to (10, 111, 'John', 4, 1) I would expect to see John move to 2, but he still stays at 1?

Comment: Because check your example it consists 3 present entry and 4 absent entry for JOHN and now if you change one entry of JOHN from absent to present than his entry becomes 4 present and 3 absent entry for him. So in both cases the difference of present and absent becomes 1 so you getting 1 for JOHN.

Comment: ok I understand how your query works now. I think what you have is ideal for the counting but I need ot add something else to say WHERE present is different to last row for that student id reset count to 0 or something similar so it counts how many in a row it has happened rather than overall?

Comment: Explain in detail with example

Comment: Thanks, I have added some clarification to the end of the question, do you still require further detail?

Answer (score 1):

If `id` from `classlist` can be used for ordering then you will get your expected result with

```
SELECT 
  s.name,
  CASE t1.presentid
    WHEN 0 THEN 'absent'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'present'
  END state,
  t1.pc  
FROM (
  SELECT
    c.id,
    c.studentid,
    c.presentid,
    @pcount := IF( @pid = presentid AND @sid = studentid, @pcount + 1, 1 ) as pc,
    @pid := presentid,
    @sid := studentid
  FROM
    classlist c
  ORDER BY
    studentid, id ) t1
  JOIN student s 
    ON t1.studentid = s.id
WHERE
  ( t1.studentid, t1.id ) IN ( SELECT 
                                 studentid, 
                                 MAX( id ) 
                               FROM classlist 
                               GROUP BY studentid );
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2d93/26)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what point about your question.
If this you want

> John present 1.
>
> Kate absent 2.
>
> Matt Present 5.

U may try this:

```
SELECT
   studentid,
   students.name AS NAME,
   SUM(presentid = 1) AS present,
   SUM(presentid = 0) AS absent,
   IF( SUM(presentid = 1)-SUM(presentid = 0)>=0,SUM(presentid = 1)-SUM(presentid = 0),SUM(presentid = 0)-SUM(presentid = 1)) AS aliase
FROM classlist
  INNER JOIN student as students ON classlist.studentid=students.id
GROUP BY studentid, NAME
```